# iOS: Drawing irregularly shaped polygons on map and knowing is user steps into/out of it

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I've worked mostly with circles on MKMapView, and I know there's a way for the OS to tell if a user has stepped into or out of a circular zone.

But what about polygons? Can the OS tell me when a user steps into or out of a polygonal zone (possibly with a dozen or more sides)? Or do I have to make calculations myself?

I know I haven't provided any code, but I wanted to know if this is even possible before delving too deep.

Comment: The automatic region monitoring logic cannot do this for you. You'd have to do the calculations yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354130/how-to-determine-if-an-annotation-is-inside-of-mkpolygonview-ios

Comment: try this
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083980/draw-on-uiimageview-over-mkmapview/16087581#16087581][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083980/draw-on-uiimageview-over-mkmapview/16087581#16087581